# How can I shorten 'item' value in Ansible console output?

Tags: ansible

I'm struggling with the title for this question, so feel free to edit it to make it more meaningful.

Let's say you have a task in Ansible and you `register` the output. For example:

```yaml
- name: Set up working directory
  shell: mktemp -d
  register: workdir
```

And I want to use the registered output to do another task. For example:

```yaml
- name: Create a file
  with_items: "{{ workdir.stdout }}"
  shell: touch {{ item }}/test-file
```

That all works great. Now, I want to loop both tasks N times. (I know I could extract this into a separate yaml file, and use `include_tasks` combined with `loop`, but I don't want to have two playbooks.) Thus, I update to:

```yaml
- name: Set up working directory
  shell: mktemp -d
  register: workdir
  loop:
  - 1
  - 2
```

As a result of the loop, the `workdir` variable has taken a different structure, so iterating through it is now slightly different. For example:

```yaml
- name: Create a file
  with_items: "{{ workdir.results }}"
  shell: touch {{ item.stdout }}/test-file
```

When the playbook is running, the Ansible console displays the entire value for "item" on each iteration.  That makes the output noisy and difficult for a human to parse visually. For example:

```
TASK [Create a file] ***************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'cmd': 'mktemp -d', 'stdout': '/tmp/tmp.a
ncF0iBqzP', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2023-05-26 15:22:46.458962'
, 'end': '2023-05-26 15:22:46.465557', 'delta': '0:00:00.006595', 'chang
ed': True, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': 'mktemp -d', '_
uses_shell': True, 'warn': True, 'stdin_add_newline': True, 'strip_empty
_ends': True, 'argv': None, 'chdir': None, 'executable': None, 'creates'
: None, 'removes': None, 'stdin': None}}, 'stdout_lines': ['/tmp/tmp.anc
F0iBqzP'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False, 'item': 1, 'ansible_loop
_var': 'item'})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'cmd': 'mktemp -d', 'stdout': '/tmp/tmp.v
Tpkvx6RK0', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2023-05-26 15:22:46.727879'
, 'end': '2023-05-26 15:22:46.734876', 'delta': '0:00:00.006997', 'chang
ed': True, 'invocation': {'module_args': {'_raw_params': 'mktemp -d', '_
uses_shell': True, 'warn': True, 'stdin_add_newline': True, 'strip_empty
_ends': True, 'argv': None, 'chdir': None, 'executable': None, 'creates'
: None, 'removes': None, 'stdin': None}}, 'stdout_lines': ['/tmp/tmp.vTp
kvx6RK0'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False, 'item': 2, 'ansible_loop
_var': 'item'})
```

Here's my question:

Is there a way to

- abbreviate the output of 'item' in the Ansible console output?
- change the loop so that it iterates differently, like:

```yaml
with_items: "{{ workdir.results.*.stdout }}"
shell: touch {{ item }}/test-file
```

- some filter that can modify the items?
- some other clever solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more options:

- Use *loop_control*. See [Limiting loop output with label](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label). For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - command: mktemp -d
      register: workdir
      with_sequence: end=2

    - command: "touch {{ item.stdout }}/test-file" 
      loop: "{{ workdir.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.stdout }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible_playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=2)

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/tmp.2pOVwfrYLI)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/tmp.FyF0JCghAo)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

- Optionally, create a list of the directories first

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    workdirs: "{{ workdir.results|map(attribute='stdout') }}"

  tasks:

    - command: mktemp -d
      register: workdir
      with_sequence: end=2

    - command: "touch {{ item }}/test-file" 
      loop: "{{ workdirs }}"
```

gives the same

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=2)

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/tmp.OOHLqAfFlX)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/tmp.T5lF2ZruwZ)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Notes:

- Use the module [*ansible.builtin.tempfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/tempfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-tempfile-module-creates-temporary-files-and-directories) instead of *command*
- Use the module [*ansible.builtin.file*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#ansible-builtin-file-module-manage-files-and-file-properties) instead of command
- Remove the temporary files as the last task.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    workdirs: "{{ workdir.results|map(attribute='path') }}"

  tasks:

    - tempfile:
        state: directory
      register: workdir
      with_sequence: end=2

    - file:
        state: touch
        path: "{{ item }}/test-file" 
      loop: "{{ workdirs }}"

    - file:
        state: absent
        path: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ workdirs }}"
```

Comment: It might be worth using an `always` block to ensure cleanup though leaving temporary files on error might be desirable as well.

Comment: The `loop_control` > `label` is exactly what I was in need of, thank you!!  And I appreciate all the other notes and tips, too.  I need to go study more about filters, they look really useful.

Comment: @Vladimir Botka I have a question about your second solution, where you list of the directories first. I notice that the play is setting the `workdirs` variable before the `workdir` variable even exists. How does order-of-operations make this function? Seems like chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: It is not a `setting` actually. It's rather a `declaration` that is evaluated on demand.  See [Lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025699/how-is-it-possible-that-ansible-loop-items-be-referenced-by-variables-outside-th/57026116#57026116).

Comment: It is also very useful to understand the `'instantiation'` of variables, i.e. when a variable becomes an attribute of *hostvars*. See [Take some variable values from one host and use them in another host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71795614/ansible-take-some-variable-values-from-one-host-and-use-them-in-another-host/71797724#71797724).